# Android 4.4 WebView Zoom centered

Tags: android, layout, webview, zooming, android-4.4-kitkat

Zoom in with the WebView (on Android < 4.4.x) rearranged / relayout the content to be inside the border of the WebView. 
But with Android 4.4.x the zoom does not rearranged / relayout the content and just zoomed into the center of the loaded website.

[image]

Does anyone can reproduce this issue?
If yes: is there any workaround for this? I need the content (mostly just text) to be inside of the WebView without scrollbars horizontal.

EDIT: the pictures are AFTER zooming.

Comment: Please provide code where you setup your webview.

Comment: I also have this issue, but zoomed in to down and right side. solution is precious

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: yes, i tried every combination of them but when I zoom, the content does not fit the width or is not changed to fit the width

Comment: Very strange, because I tried it on android 4.42 and it works. And according [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#Zoom), it should work too.

Comment: what haveyou tried exactly? Android changed the WebView in 4.4.2 to the ChromeBrowser, and it reacty exactly like the browser, but different to the old version. Which settings dit you set? any ChriomeClient or something?

Comment: I've tried to add this lines in my app and then run it on nexus 5. Webview became without scroll.

Comment: yes but when you zoom it will be still like this and not rearrange the content to fit the width again

Comment: the images are both AFTER zooming in with pinch or zoomIn() method

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I found that if you call to:

```
 webview.setInitialScale(webview.getScale()*100);
```

It cause the text to rearrange, just like we want.
The problem is that after calling this function, it set the 'webview.getScale()' to be the base scaling of the text and it disables the zoom out (-) option (since this is now the minimum zoom level).
This is the best thing I found so far.

Did you find any other better soultion?

Comment: My solution was, I change the CSS of the HTML and reload the page. I put an placeholder like %SIZE% into the CSS and before loading the HTML I set this placeholder. The reload will cause the rearange. Its not nice and will not work in every case.